# Make Vertex Normals Perpendicular to face in smooth shading

Tags: normals

Making a face shaded flat automatically makes all the vertex normals parallel to the face normal. However two flat faces touching each other will not share their vertex normals.

Basically select the face, press a button (or run a script), and have the normals automatically align without changing the shading. Right now I can only do this using Data Transfer and Vertex groups.

[image]